# Sculpting Dynamic topology or detail flood fill?

Tags: sculpting, dynamic-topology

I have been watching a few different YouTubers that are posting time-lapses of there work and I have seen a sudden jump up in using almost no Dynamic topology at all. They are just using detail flood will and continue on. I have seen some replies to comments and they YouTubers mentioned preserving the quads of there mesh.

Is there no point in Dyntopo now and I should switch to that method?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a change from the 2.7x sculpting workflow to 2.8

You can still use dynamic topology but it's not the recommended workflow anymore.

The new workflow is sculpting on the static mesh and remeshing.

Pablo Dobarros Talk about the new tools and how they work:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lxkyA4Xslzs

Hand on with Julien Kasper using the 2.8 workflow:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YaVEJTLDD3Y

Comment: Great Thanks you so much for the answer its been stressing me out haha!